# JAVA weird String comparison issue

Tags: java, string

Here is a very weird problem in java string comparison. I am actually a novice in java, so please pardon if I am understanding it wrong.

The goal is to get the url for which text is "Next?" should be assigned to nextLink. The first if block is able to find "Next" in my linkText String object, but the second if block is failing.

Here is the code:

```
String linkText = link.text().trim();
if(linkText.contains("Next"))
{
    System.out.println(" Contains Out :" + "  " + linkText);
    nextLink = link;
}

if(linkText.equals("Next?"))
{
    System.out.println(" Equals Out :" + "  " + linkText);
    nextLink = link;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Contains Out :  Next?
```

As you can see in the console output, the value of `linkText` is `Next?`.

Shouldn't `equals()` be true in this case?

### EDIT

Message changed for two if blocks. equals() also shows same behavior.

Comment: Are you sure ? is actually a ? character (hex 3F).  It looks like somethign is just not displaying the right charset to me.

Comment: With both of the test cases outputting exactly the same message, how would you determine which if statement was successful?

Comment: If `linkText` were actually the String "Next?" then both if statements would evaluate as true.  I don't think your input is what you think it is.

Comment: Sorry, can you do `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(linkText.getBytes("US-ASCII")));` and check if the last value is `63` .

Comment: @Anand. Checked constant as well as variable "linkText". Getting same output: [78, 101, 120, 116, 63]
[78, 101, 120, 116, 63]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing with`equalsIgnoreCase(...)` which will ignore case but only match strings of equal length, but searching with `contains(...)` which won't ignore case and will match substrings within the main string.

Comment: Doesn't ignoreCase widens the scope for equality? equals() also showing same behavior

Comment: @achbee Thanks for the comment.  You're right.  The explanation covered half the issue, and it is broken in two ways.

Answer (score 0):

`str.contains(charsequence)` checks if the char sequence is contained inside the string.

`str.equalsIgnoreCase(string)` checks if both strings are equal, ignoring case.

try this if you wanna check if the text is CONTAINED in the link:

```
String linkText = link.text().trim();

if(linkText.toLowerCase().contains() ("Next?".toLowerCase())){

System.out.printf(" * a ===> : <%s>  (%s)\n", link.attr("abs:href"), link.text());
    nextLink = link;

}
 if(linkText.contains ("Next")){

    System.out.printf(" * a ===> : <%s>  (%s)\n", link.attr("abs:href"), link.text());
    nextLink = link;

}
```

try this if you wanna check if the text EQUALS the link:

```
String linkText = link.text().trim();

if(linkText.equals("Next?"){

System.out.printf(" * a ===> : <%s>  (%s)\n", link.attr("abs:href"), link.text());
    nextLink = link;

}
if(linkText.equals("Next")){

    System.out.printf(" * a ===> : <%s>  (%s)\n", link.attr("abs:href"), link.text());
    nextLink = link;

}
```

in this code I'm checking if `"Next?"` with lower case is contained in the full url with lower case.